# Problem accessing item through data attribute

Tags: css

With css, I need to customize the button: background-color, font-size, etc.
The HTML is:

```
<a href="#" data-context="desk">
    <button type="button">Button</button>
</a>
```

Could you help me please.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you clearly didn't search about how to use css

Comment: Your HTML is **invalid**. `a` is not allowed to have interactive content like `button`, nor can a `button` contain an `a`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[data-context="desk"] button` to write css, here is the example:

```css
[data-context="desk"] button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #28a745;
  border-color: #28a745;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-context="desk">
  <button type="button">Button</button>
</a>
```

Comment: The HTML is **invalid**. `a` is not allowed to have interactive content like `button`, nor can a `button` contain an `a`. Please don't suggest solutions for invalid HTML without explicitly pointing that out, and suggesting a fix.

Comment: The code comes from native Woocommerce plugin so even it is invalid, it is relevant!!